# Indistinguishability of Mixed and Pure States in Complex Systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurements, quantum-states

Consider the following two states:

1. $\left|\psi\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|\psi_1\right\rangle\otimes\left|\chi_1\right\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\psi_2\right\rangle\otimes\left|\chi_2\right\rangle$
2. $\left|\psi\right\rangle = $ a mixed state which has 1/2 probability of being $\left|\psi_1\right\rangle\otimes\left|\chi_1\right\rangle$and 1/2 probability of being $\left|\psi_2\right\rangle\otimes\left|\chi_2\right\rangle$

The setting is such that $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are eigenstates of a certain observable $\Psi$ with eigenvalues 1 and 2, while $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are the states of a measurement apparatus. So $\left|\psi_1\right\rangle\otimes\left|\chi_1\right\rangle$ means that the object+apparatus state is such that the apparatus measures the object to be in state 1, and similarly for $\left|\psi_2\right\rangle\otimes\left|\chi_2\right\rangle$.

There is no doubt that the mixed state option is qualitatively different from the pure state option. But Eugene Wigner claims in his essay "Remarks on the Mind-Body Questions" that when the apparatus is complex (meaning that $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are states with many more degrees of freedom than $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$), it is difficult to make the distinguishment.

So my question is: **how and why is it difficult to distinguish mixed state from pure state when $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are complex?** Maybe a complexity theory viewpoint would be of help here? I don't know.

Comment: Questions of the kind "What does author X mean" are somewhat tricky to answer.  But I would *guess* what is meant is that if one cannot measure in a basis which is a linear combination of $|\chi_1\rangle$ and $|\chi_2\rangle$ -- e..g, since the two states involve many particles, and large superpositions are hard to create/measure (but the same could be the case, e.g., due to some superselection rule) -- such a superposition is indistinguishable from a mixture.

Comment: I agree with @NorbertSchuch, but perhaps the point is that in order to calculate the expectation value of $\psi$ one would have to trace over an enormous number of states of $\chi$, the result looking very much like a mixed state.

Comment: @garyp If you want to compute a general expectation value w.r.t. $\psi$, you better *not* trace over a large number of particles!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch One traces over unobserved variables, no?  Perhaps I've misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @garyp A general measurement of $\psi$ should involve both parts of the system.  If one only measures the first part, the mixture and superposition are indeed completely identical -- if $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are orthogonal, this is, which is not mentioned in the question.  (But if they weren't, the superposition and the mixture were different in pretty much any scenario.)

Comment: The statement may also have to do with the fact that for $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$ orthogonal and $\chi_1$, $\chi_2$ with many degrees of freedom, a statistical superposition of $\psi_1\otimes \chi_1$, $\psi_2\otimes \chi_2$ has negligible entropy compared to any thermal (or simply mixed) states of the apparatus. In this sense the statistical superposition is "very close" to the pure state superposition of zero entropy.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: But I guess if we have a complex system with a large number of degrees of freedom, chances are good, that $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are orthogonal. If I pick random vectors, they'd be nearly orthogonal. Of course, one needs to posit that the vectors are random...